# Android check if Arraylist contains another Arraylist?

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I have tried almost every solution from SO and they aren't working correctly. I have a few `ArrayList<Integer>` that I am trying to compare with another `ArrayList<Integer>`, but the code keeps telling me there is no match, even when I directly create one that matches.

```
private ArrayList<Integer> list_of_twos = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,2,2));
public int getValue(Arraylist<Integer> currentList){
   if (currentList.contains(list_of_twos)) 
   {
       return 6;
   }
}
```

I am creating the currentList in my oncreate for the moment for testing like this

```
private ArrayList<Integer> testCurrentList = new ArrayList<>();
testCurrentList.add(2);
testCurrentList.add(2);
testCurrentList.add(2);

int value = getValue(testCurrentList);
```

I have tried `containsall` but then it gives me false positives as well.

Comment: The `contains` method checks if the collection contains the given _element_. As you have a `List<Integer>`, which means every element is an instance of `Integer`, that list cannot legitimately contain a `List<?>` element. Are you actually trying to see if one list contains a sub-list?

Comment: Does the 2's need to be consecutive or does the list just need to contain 3 2's? e.g. should 2, 2, 3, 2 return true or false?

Comment: They are consecutive back cause I sort the list first.

Answer (score 0):

The `ArrayList.contains(Object)` method returns true if the parameter object is found between the ArrayList elements. Since you have an `ArrayList` of `Integer` but you're passing as argument an `ArrayList<Integer>` the function will always return false since it's comparing integers with a full Array.

To solve the problem you can use `.equals()` method:
`if (currentList.equals(list_of_twos))`

Or you could implement your own comparing function using a loop (or stream) to iterate through the elements of one array and compare them to the other one.

Comment: Well sometimes the array can contain other numbers as well, so while my example only shows 2,2,2 in reality it could be 2,2,2,4,6 as well, so equals doesn't work.

Comment: equals compares every position of the list with the element in the same position of the other list so even if you have list1={2,2,2,4,6} and list2={2,2,2,4,6} it will return true, but if instead list2={2,4,2,6,2} it will return false. If that’s not what you’re looking for please explain better what you need so I can provide a better solution